# cannot start a docker image with an USB device onMACOSX

Tags: macos, docker, tty

On ubuntu, I'm starting a docker to broadcast usb input on TCP:

```
docker run -d -p "2000:2000" --device "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0" akshmakov/serialport-server:latest /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It works perfectly.

on MacOs 11.3.1 with the following docker version:

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.6
```

when I execute the command line :

```
docker run -d -p "2000:2000" --device "/dev/cu.usbmodem14101:/dev/ttyUSB0" akshmakov/serialport-server:latest /dev/ttyUSB0
```

there's the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/cu.usbmodem14101": no such file or directory.
```

/dev/cu.usbmodem14101 device exists.

I can cat it

```
cat /dev/cu.usbmodem14101
$GNTXT,01,01,02,u-blox AG - www.u-blox.com*4E
$GNTXT,01,01,02,HW UBX-M8030 00080000*60
$GNTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 3.01 (107888)*2B
...
```

Adding the --privileged parameter in the command line doesn't help

Is there anyone who had the same problem and has a solution to this ?
Thank you.

Comment: It's something with privileges. P.S. maybe --privileged can help, but I'd like to find better way

Answer (score -2):

Try switching the usb cable for a better one. That fixed it for me.

Comment: welcome to SO , It is better to write this answer in the comment

Comment: thank you for the welcome! Can you please explain the rationale for using a comment instead of an answer? I thought the reply should be a new answer per the comment help page, but I'd be happy to learn if that's incorrect:


When shouldn't I comment?

Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
. . .
Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);